# magento2 -custom layout file not loading

Tags: magento2, layout, error, blocks

i have followed the below link in order to get check if our custom layout xml file is loaded or not using the event: **layout_generate_blocks_after**

In the log file i just get:

**2016-06-29T11:07:40+00:00 INFO (6):**

```
 <layout/>
```

which should actually load my custom layout file :
catalogsearch_catalogsearch_resultcontroller.xml

Could any1 please help why my layout file is not loading.

UPDATED: LAYOUT file **catalogsearch_catalogsearch_resultcontroller.xml**

**controller path:**

- Vendor\Module\Controller\Catalog
- Vendor\Module\Controller\CatalogSearch
- Vendor\Module\Controller\CatalogSearch\Result.php
- Vendor\Module\Controller\CatalogSearch\ResultController.php

**\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalogsearch_catalogsearch_resultcontroller.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
     <referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.leftnav"><arguments>
        <argument name="setTemplate" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module::search/filter.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="product_searchlist_toolbar">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module::toolbar/toolbar.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
     </referenceBlock>  

</body>
```

Above xml was replicated from 1x code which was as :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
 <catalogsearch_result_index>        
    <reference name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <setTemplate>/filter.phtml</setTemplate>
        </action>
    </reference>
      <reference name="content">
        <reference type="catalogsearch/result" name="search.result">
            <reference name="search_result_list">
                <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <template>toolbar.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                 </reference>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
 </layout>
```

**system.log :**

```
Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_3d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e and handles : Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
```

Comment: Could you please post the code of your layout file ?

Comment: i have updated the layout file

Comment: layout ending tag is already there, i just forgot to give tab while adding question. and its magento1x code which i had replicated to magento2x layout file where the issue is

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

It is because your file is not properly named.

It should be `catalogsearch_result_index.xml` instead of `catalogsearch_catalogsearch_resultcontroller.xml`

Comment: thats the magento1x xml file, which i forgot to tab while adding question...</layout> is already there.

Comment: But i dont have result/index in my custom module... i have the controller path as shown... should i still give catalogsearch_result_index.xml name instead, with just content replaced

Comment: i followed... routerfrontname_controlleraction_controllername.xml for naming the layout of my custom xml... is it rite?  or should i use the default magentos catalogsearch_result_index

Comment: please see my system .log says in my updated answer

Comment: any update @Raphael

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: Did any one find the solution for this issue?